# Nest LazyColumn and LazyRow with scrollbar , horizontal scroll abnormal

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Nest LazyColumn and LazyRow to show table data, vertical scroll bar work ok, but horizental scroll bar working only on bottom row and no align, how to fix it?

Horizental scroll not align:

[image: Horizental scroll not align]

```
@Composable
fun showLogPreview() {
    val colState = rememberLazyListState()
    val rowState = rememberLazyListState()
    var rStr="R"
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn (state = colState, modifier = Modifier.padding(all=8.dp)){
            println("LogPreview update, myVM.csvContent!!.size=" + myVM.csvContent!!.size)
            items(100) { rowIdx ->
                rStr="R"+rowIdx
                LazyRow (state=rowState, modifier = Modifier.padding(all=0.dp)){
                    items(20) { colIdx ->
                        TextField(
                            readOnly = true,
                            singleLine = true,
                            textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 12.sp),
                            value = "C$colIdx",
                            label = { Text(text=rStr, style = TextStyle(fontSize = 10.sp)) },
                            onValueChange = {},
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(100.dp)
                                .height(50.dp)
                                .border(1.dp, Color.DarkGray)
                                .background(Color.White)
                                .padding(all=0.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        VerticalScrollbar(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd).fillMaxHeight(),
            adapter = rememberScrollbarAdapter( scrollState = colState)
        )
        HorizontalScrollbar(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter).fillMaxWidth(),
            adapter = rememberScrollbarAdapter( scrollState = rowState)
        )
    }
}
```

When scroll vertical bar , horizental position align ok, why ??